# Convert DVDSUB to srt and then to mkv

Tags: video, dvd

I have ripped a lot of my dvd's. But it is in an ugly and non-supported DVDSUB format. I saw in Subtitle edit I could convert it to srt. I tried it and it works great. But there is one thing, it costs a lot of time. Is there any way I could automate the process of the convert DVDSUB and then use mkvtoolnix to set it with the video.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What research did you do and what have you tried to find a solution by yourself?